# Android - Fastest data parsing from JsonElement to array list of objects

Tags: android, json, performance, parsing

I have this code:

```
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JsonElement result,
                            Exception error, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                        if (error == null) {
                            JsonObject jo = result.getAsJsonObject();
                            JsonElement pom = jo.get("data");
                            JsonArray ja = pom.getAsJsonArray();

                            int size = ja.size();

                            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                Action actualAction = new Gson().fromJson(
                                        ja.get(i), Action.class);

                             //Some code....
                            }
                        }

                        if (dialog != null)
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Is this the fastest way how to parse data from JsonElement to my class "Action"? Example of JsonElement data is [here](http://pastebin.com/tHcLNiqp) (in real, there is more then 1000 objects). What way to parse data you recommend?

Comment: Have a look at GSon it is very fast

Comment: Use something like this:
         Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Action>>() {}.getType();       ArrayList<Action> test = new Gson().fromJson(result, listType); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google [Gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

tutorial is  [here](http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/using-gson-to-parse-json-on-android/)

Comment: Use something like this: Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Action>>() {}.getType();       ArrayList<Action> test = new Gson().fromJson(result, listType); ?

Comment: you need to create classes for each object type...and then pass the reference of the parent class to gson ....you can see the example ..